# Trouble loading an objects src in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am still a bit new to React and posting on this forum so please bear with me.  I currently have two React files which I believe are talking to each other, but there seems to be a disconnect when trying to pull information from an object.  One of my React files is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

export class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const src = this.props.src;
    const alt = this.props.alt;
    const width = this.props.width;
    const height = this.props.height;
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">Will''s weird online shop thing I have no idea about</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          Click the arrows to browse through the different items.
        </p>
        <img src={src} alt={alt} width={width} height={height} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

and the other is :

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import './index.css';
    import {App} from './App';
    import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
    import dogbag from './images/dogbag.jpg';

    const DogBagObj = {
        src: dogbag,
        alt: 'Cute dog handbag',
        height: '100px',
        width: '70px'
    };

    const Items = [
      DogBagObj,
      'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/f4/bd/0bf4bd031a363fc68b56afe6289f450f--random-pokemon-pokemon-stuff.jpg',
      'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/881211588748988416/zQL9OLuc_400x400.jpg',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg/1200px-Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg'
    ]

    class OnlineStore extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);

            this.state = { currentItem: 0 };

            this.interval = null;

            this.changeItem = this.changeItem.bind(this);
        }

        changeItem() {
            let current = this.state.currentItem;
            let next = ++current % Items.length;
            this.setState({ currentItem: next });
        }

        componentDidMount() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.changeItem, 1000);
      }

        render() {
            const src = Items[this.state.currentItem];
            return <App src={src} />;
        }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(
        <OnlineStore />, 
        document.getElementById('root'));
    registerServiceWorker();
```

I am confident that I have correctly imported the dogbag.jpg from the image folder and the three images which have direct links to them load correctly.
I feel like my problem lies within getting the DogBagObj.src to correctly read.  If I change DogBagObj in the Items array to dogbag it will load the image but I would also like the ability to control multiple tags for each image (such as the alt, height and width).  Is there some minor syntax error I am over looking or is this a problem which would be much harder to remedy?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `items` array contains multiple data structure but you treat it as if it contains only one.
Either use strings only or objects only.
For example..

**Strings only:**

```
   const Items = [
      DogBagObj.src,
      'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/f4/bd/0bf4bd031a363fc68b56afe6289f450f--random-pokemon-pokemon-stuff.jpg',
      'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/881211588748988416/zQL9OLuc_400x400.jpg',
      'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg/1200px-Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg'
    ]
```

**Or use objects with similar data structure:**

```
const Items = [
      DogBagObj,
      {src:'https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0b/f4/bd/0bf4bd031a363fc68b56afe6289f450f--random-pokemon-pokemon-stuff.jpg'},
      {src:'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/881211588748988416/zQL9OLuc_400x400.jpg'},
      {src:'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/74/Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg/1200px-Sun-crypto-accelerator-1000.jpg'}
    ]
```

And in your `render` method:

```
render() {
    const src = Items[this.state.currentItem].src;
    return <App src={src} />;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, as I'm sure you know that fixed my problem.